# Software to find duplicate videos that have been resized

Tags: video, photos.app

I have duplicate videos in my Photos library, but the videos have been resized so they are not detected by normal duplicate file finding software. Does anyone know if any software for OSX that will find duplicate videos that have been resized?

Comment: Wow! That is a very challenging/awesome question coding wise. This would make a great hobby project! :D But to answer you question: No, not that I know of, but maybe Singlemizer from the App Store will work. To be honest though, I don't think so. It doesn't say anything about video support in the description, and if it does support videos it will probably only support exact copies.